# Vectorize/Speed up Code with Nested For Loops

Tags: r

The code below generates the desired output. However, the lack of vectorizing means it runs very slowly. How can I speed it up?

I've put the `dput` results from part of some indicative data.

**Input `dput`s**

1. `StandRef` input

   ```
   structure(list(id = structure(c(43L, 50L, 17L, 45L, 9L, 5L, 49L, 
   33L, 48L, 39L, 71L, 64L, 44L, 47L, 58L, 24L, 15L, 37L, 14L, 11L, 
   26L, 57L, 4L, 30L, 72L, 21L, 23L, 60L, 38L, 59L, 29L, 19L, 6L, 
   46L, 36L, 3L, 63L, 55L, 51L, 35L, 10L, 7L, 16L, 73L, 42L, 52L, 
   41L, 27L, 25L, 61L, 20L, 70L, 53L, 18L, 31L, 22L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 
   40L, 65L, 67L, 28L, 56L, 13L, 32L, 54L, 66L, 68L, 34L, 12L, 69L, 
   62L), .Label = c("ID 1009445", "ID 120763", "ID 133883", "ID 136398", 
   "ID 171850", "ID 192595", "ID 197597", "ID 216406", "ID 21888", 
   "ID 230940", "ID 23777", "ID 282791", "ID 306348", "ID 309745", 
   "ID 326928", "ID 344897", "ID 34974", "ID 350157", "ID 391831", 
   "ID 402479", "ID 43010", "ID 484078", "ID 484697", "ID 537134", 
   "ID 562259", "ID 562455", "ID 567042", "ID 572866", "ID 578945", 
   "ID 595683", "ID 59759", "ID 598460", "ID 603611", "ID 603757", 
   "ID 607991", "ID 60976", "ID 622720", "ID 646989", "ID 656144", 
   "ID 668807", "ID 669435", "ID 720522", "ID 740555", "ID 745499", 
   "ID 746001", "ID 783969", "ID 78979", "ID 792426", "ID 793541", 
   "ID 797860", "ID 806559", "ID 810517", "ID 826054", "ID 837609", 
   "ID 839287", "ID 867918", "ID 869788", "ID 875380", "ID 876870", 
   "ID 882220", "ID 893116", "ID 895909", "ID 899050", "ID 900143", 
   "ID 908100", "ID 912185", "ID 916371", "ID 916620", "ID 957879", 
   "ID 966195", "ID 993247", "ID 998911", "ID 999610"), class = "factor"), 
       region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L), location = c(259090L, 559306L, 2227063L, 2369217L, 4026978L, 
       4211264L, 4679449L, 5105226L, 5106345L, 5344670L, 5473601L, 
       5476528L, 5871970L, 6461228L, 6700029L, 6708265L, 7639959L, 
       9297695L, 10254788L, 10328812L, 11102816L, 11568295L, 11720437L, 
       12843457L, 14012506L, 14156669L, 14632300L, 14641938L, 15298211L, 
       15468425L, 15534406L, 16279682L, 16699353L, 17226952L, 17320785L, 
       269017L, 453097L, 828833L, 954610L, 954842L, 1066378L, 1217332L,  
       1253530L, 1277716L, 1292857L, 1337952L, 1439657L, 1452989L, 
       1712345L, 1758035L, 2601630L, 2640359L, 2778095L, 3151129L, 
       3369931L, 3399080L, 3529525L, 3810217L, 3821120L, 3841588L, 
       3901557L, 4111633L, 4220440L, 4528632L, 4665450L, 5099307L, 
       5260242L, 5958770L, 5966356L, 6137405L, 6246065L, 6297231L, 
       6807949L)), .Names = c("id", "region", "location"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
   -73L))
   ```
2. Two sample inputs

Sample 1

```
        structure(list(region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
        begin = c(0L, 2259252L, 5092077L, 9158205L, 0L, 135094L, 
        941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L), finish = c(2259252L, 5092077L, 
        9158205L, 20463033L, 135094L, 941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L, 
        7092402L), sed = c(3.98106154985726, 7.51649828394875, 5.15440228627995, 
        2.67456624889746, 7.54309412557632, 4.17413910385221, 7.47043058509007, 
        6.13362524658442, 1.00084994221106)), .Names = c("region", 
        "begin", "finish", "sed"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -9L))
```

Sample 2

```
        structure(list(region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
        begin = c(0L, 2253252L, 7091077L, 9120205L, 0L, 135094L, 
        941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L), finish = c(2253252L, 7091077L, 
        9120205L, 17463033L, 135094L, 941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L, 
        7092402L), sed = c(3.31830840984048, 1.38014704208403, 6.13049140975458, 
        2.10349875097134, 0.48170587509345, 0.13058713509175, 9.13509713513509, 
        6.13047153058701, 3.81734081501503)), .Names = c("region", 
        "begin", "finish", "sed"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -9L))
```

**Unvectorized Code**

```
matchLocationsToRegions <- function(path) {     
# get list of data files (around 500 of these; only dput of 2 given: sample262519 and sample252519)
setwd(path,sep="",collapse=NULL)
data_files <- list.files()

# read in template file with complete regional boundaries
standRef <- read.table(paste(path, "StandRef.txt",sep="",collapse=NULL), header=TRUE, sep="\t")

# pre-allocate a df with row dimensions of standRef and num of columns according to num of data files
sediment.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(standRef),ncol=length(data_files)))
colnames(sediment.df) <- data_files
rownames(sediment.df) <- standRef[,1]

# create a counter for columns filled
col_counter <- 1    

for (file in data_files) {
    # read in current, processed data
    sample <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")          

    # pre-allocate vectors for sedimentation data vector
    sed <- rep(NA, nrow(standRef))

    # create a variable to track end boundary for a particular sample_ID
    end_tracker <- 1

    index <- unlist(lapply (unique(standRef$region), function(reg) {
             reg.filter <- which(standRef$region == reg)
             samp.filter <- which(sample$region == reg)
             samp.filter[cut(standRef$location[reg.filter],c(0L,sample$finish[samp.filter]),labels=F)]
        }))
    sed <- sample$sed[index]

    # fill in next, unfilled column of relevant df with data from relevant vector
    sediment.df[col_counter] <- sed   

    # update column counter variable 
    col_counter <- col_counter + 1
}       

# save df as a table
write.table(sediment.df,file="samples_sed.txt", row.names=TRUE, sep="\t") 
}
```

Running `Rprof` showed that 
`"scan" "read.table" "matchLocationsToRegions"` and
`"type.convert" "read.table" "matchLocationsToRegions"`
predominate runtime. Presumably, there's a bottleneck by for-looping over this line:

```
sample <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

Update: `for` loop over the regions has been replaced with much faster-executing code (h/t Simon Urbanek). However, the rest is quite slow.

Comment: I suggest you try to run a `Rprof()` first and see where the bottle necks are.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Added some info from `Rprof`

Comment: Try Statistics SE, there are quite a few people with skills in R there.

Comment: @check123 I think this question is pretty apt for SO.

Comment: @Kaleb feel free to drop by at the R chatroom, no sense of running a conversation here.

Comment: Just a tip on reading in files: I find it much better to use `foreach` to read in a lot of files, then aggregate them.  If there are multiple cores, this can reduce the total time spent loading files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the loop easily:

```
sediment.df <- as.data.frame(lapply(data_files, function(file) {
   sample <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")          
   index <- unlist(lapply (unique(standRef$region), function(reg) {
         reg.filter <- which(standRef$region == reg)
         samp.filter <- which(sample$region == reg)
          samp.filter[cut(standRef$location[reg.filter],c(0L,sample$finish[samp.filter]),labels=F)]
    }))
    sample$sed[index]
}))
colnames(sediment.df) <- data_files
rownames(sediment.df) <- standRef[,1]
```

However, it is not unlikely that a lot of time is spent in `read.table` so you may consider a) using `scan`, b) creating just one file with all samples (e.g. use an extra column to define the sample) so you don't need to load many files.

Comment: I know this isn't in the question, but if I had to return `sample$borewidth[index]` as well as `sample$sed[index]` and put it in its own dataframe (e.g. `borewidth.df`), how would I do this, without having to create a separate `as.data.frame(lapply...` structure again, which would not be good since it would require running over the sample files twice? Creating one, aggregate sample file is not really possible, since the files vary. Thanks.

Comment: With more than one vector result it loses some of the convenience -- you can return a matrix for example instead of one vector, but then you'll need an extra step to split all columns into two (there other many ways, too).As for the aggregate file - what do you mean vary? You use fixed columns from it so you can certainly put it into one file with an extra ID column denoting the source file.

Comment: I suppose it is possible to have one aggregate file. But wouldn't that mean having `"sourceid" "region" "begin" "finish" "sed" "borewidth"` columns x 500 (3000 cols) or am I misinterpreting you? Is that a problem wrt memory?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant and, no, you can have millions of rows with no problem.