# Use of x`apply` to speed up loops

Tags: r

This is a more focussed question based on another question I have open at [Vectorize/Speed up Code with Nested For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691966/vectorize-speed-up-code-with-nested-for-loops)

Basically, I want to speed up the execution of this code. I was thinking of using one of the `apply` family of functions. The `apply` function would have to use/perform the following:

**Input**: loop over regions 1 to 10; vectors `sed` and `borewidth` with preallocated dimensions filled with NAs

**Process**: fill data in each of `sed` and `borewidth` in the manner implemented in the inner `for` loop

**Output**: `sed` and `borewidth` vectors

**Assumptions** (h/t Simon Urbanek): the begin, finish points of each row are contiguous, sequential and for each region, begin at 0.

Code is as below:

```
for (region in 1:10) {             
    # subset standRef and sample by region code
    standRef.region <- standRef[which(standRef$region == region),]
    sample.region <- sample[which(sample$region == region),]

    for (i in 1:nrow(sample.region))
    {
        # create a dataframe - locations - that includes: 
        # 1) those indices of standRef.region in which the value of the location column is greater than the value of the ith row of the begin column of sample.region
        # 2) those indices of standRef.region in which the value of the location column is less than the value of the ith row of the finish column of sample.region
        locations <- standRef.region[which((standRef.region$location > sample.region$begin[i]) & (standRef.region$location < sample.region$finish[i])),]
        sed[end_tracker:(end_tracker + nrow(locations))] <- sample.region$sed[i]   
        borewidth[end_tracker:(end_tracker + nrow(locations))] <- sample.region$borewidth[i]

        # update end_tracker to the number of locations rows for this iteration
        end_tracker <- end_tracker + nrow(locations)                
    }
    cat("Finished region", region,"\n")            
}
```

Sample Data for `borewidth` and`sed`. Edit: corrected formatting error in `dput`

```
structure(list(region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
begin = c(0L, 2253252L, 7091077L, 9120205L, 0L, 135094L, 
941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L), finish = c(2253252L, 7091077L, 
9120205L, 17463033L, 135094L, 941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L, 
7092402L), sed = c(3.31830840984048, 1.38014704208403, 6.13049140975458, 
2.10349875097134, 0.48170587509345, 0.13058713509175, 9.13509713513509, 
6.13047153058701, 3.81734081501503), borewidth = c(3L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("region", "begin", 
"finish", "sed", "borewidth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

TIA.

Comment: `split` and `lapply` will help with the outer loop. You may also want to consider `merge`-ing the 2 data frames to do this without explicit loops if its possible.

Comment: some (dummy) data would make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Thierry, some sample data up. The reference data - `standRef` - is provided in `dput` format in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691966/vectorize-speed-up-code-with-nested-for-loops. Thanks

Comment: @James I've tried using `sapply` by putting the code above into a function `foo1` and calling it from `vecOfData <- sapply(vecOfData, function(x) foo1(1:10))`, where `vecOfData <- c(sed, borewidth)`. However, this just seems to loop through each element in `sed`and then `borewidth` -- over a million iterations! -- rather than treating each vector as an element.How can I use `split` in the context above? Thanks.

Comment: Please give us code to generate the datasets that will work with a simple copy-paste. The structure() generates just one data.frame. Is that sed or borewidth? And we don't have the sample data.frame (which can be confused with the sample() function).

Comment: @Thierry: The `dput` above (i.e. structure()) is the sample dataframe. It contains data for both `sed` (4th column) and `borewidth` (fifth column). Does the `dput` output work for you? I've corrected a typo in the code.

Comment: Start by removing all calls to `which` -- they are redundant since R has logic indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some extra assumptions based on the data you posted (incl. the other question), this is one way you could do it:

```
index <- unlist(lapply (unique(standRef$region), function(reg) {
   reg.filter <- which(standRef$region == reg)
   samp.filter <- which(sample$region == reg)
   samp.filter[cut(standRef$location[reg.filter],c(0L,sample$finish[samp.filter]),labels=F)]
}))
sed <- sample$sed[index]
borewidth <- sample$borewidth[index]
```

The extra assumption is that your samples are contiguous, sequential (all your examples were) and start at 0. This allows us to use `cut()` on the `$finish` instead of treating each interval separately. One difference is that you code left gaps at the breaks, but I'm assuming that was not intentional.

Comment: Does this replace all of my code above, or does it fit into a particular part of it? Sorry for being a bit dense on that: I've never heard of many of the functions you're using. Thanks. Re: assumptions: contiguous -- yes should be; sequential: yes; start at 0 for a given region: yep.

Comment: It replaces all your code. `unique(standRef$region)` gives you all the regions, so the function runs over all regions as `reg`. For each region it splits  the `location` for the region into pieces given by `finish` using `cut()`. That gives you the index *within* the region, so the trick is to map back into the full-size `sample` by plugging it in `samp.filter[..]` which gives you the index in `sample`. Since the order is preserved you can just concatenate the result (via `unlist`) to give you full mapping from each row in `sample` to the rows in `standRef`.

Comment: Tested the code on my datasets. Two observations: it works and it's fast, very fast. Thankyou!!! Any tips on how to speed up the rest of the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691966/vectorize-speed-up-code-with-nested-for-loops?? The blazing speed of this section is incongruent with the rest. Thanks again!

Comment: In the other question you may want to create just one file instead of looping over all the files - `read.table` is fairly slow in general. But even if you don't do that you can replace all the outer code with just one `lapply`: `lapply(data_files, function(file) { ...; sample$sed[index] })` - it is a typical example of a misplaced loop.

Comment: How - within `function(file)` - do I 1) update `sediment.df` and other dataframes? 2) return the `sediment.df` and other dataframes? Is `unlist` needed again? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to update anything - that is the point since `lapply` will give you the result for each column in a list - you get everything in one go (you can call `as.data.frame` on the result if you wish). You need to get into the functional way of thinking - there is no need to modify things, you simply return what you need. No, you don't need `unlist` because you don't want to flatten the list into one vector.